# Getting error: Type 'typeof B' is not assignable to type 'typeof A' for class B that extends A

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, typeof

Reproducible example [here](https://cutt.ly/fkFIjaP)

My need is: the `contentType` parameter should accept any class object extended from Content (PublicContent, AdminContent, PrivateContent, etc) and I want to call a static method from this parameter type inside the `execute` method.

I have a method with the following signature:

```
async execute<U extends ContentProps>(input: {
    contentType: typeof Content;
    contentPropsType: typeof ContentProps; 
}): Promise<Result<U, Failure>>;
```

and a class hierarchy as follows:

```
// content.entity.ts

export class ContentProps extends EntityProps {}

export class Content<T extends ContentProps> extends Entity<T> {
  public constructor(props: T) {
    super(props);
  }
}

// public-content.entity.ts
export class PublicContentProps extends ContentProps {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly text: string;
}

export class PublicContent extends Content<PublicContentProps> {
  constructor(props: PublicContentProps) {
    super(props);
  }
  // ommited
}
```

The issue is that when I call the `execute` method passing `PublicContent` as the `contentType` parameter I'm getting an error saying

> Type 'typeof PublicContent' is not assignable to type 'typeof Content'

The method call is:

```
const result = await this.getContent.execute({
  contentType: PublicContent,
  contentPropsType: PublicContentProps,
});
```

My question is: Why I'm getting this error since `PublicContent` is extending `Content`?

**EDIT:** as requested by @Chase, the full types for `Entity` and `EntityProps`:

```
// entity.ts
export abstract class EntityProps extends BaseEntityProps {
  id?: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}

export abstract class Entity<T extends EntityProps> extends BaseEntity<T> {
  get id(): string {
    return this.props.id;
  }

  get createdAt(): Date {
    return this.props.createdAt;
  }

  get updatedAt(): Date {
    return this.props.updatedAt;
  }

  protected constructor(entityProps: T) {
    super(entityProps);
  }
}


// base.entity.ts
export abstract class BaseEntityProps {}

export abstract class BaseEntity<T extends BaseEntityProps> extends Equatable {
  protected readonly props: T;

  protected constructor(baseEntityProps: T) {
    super();
    this.props = baseEntityProps;
  }

  static create<T = BaseEntity<BaseEntityProps>, U = BaseEntityProps>(
    this: {
      new (entityProps: U): T;
    },
    propsType: { new (): U },
    props: U,
  ): Result<T, ValidationFailure> {
    const violations = validateSchemaSync(propsType, props);

    return violations?.length
      ? Result.fail(new ValidationFailure(violations))
      : Result.ok(new this({ ...props }));
  }

  toJSON(): T {
    return this.props;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the `typeof`? `typeof Content` gives you the type of class object (static side), wheras `Content` is the instance side type. So it shouldn't be compatible. If you want to refer to the instance side (an object instantiated from the class) - remove the `typeof`s

Comment: @Chase this is because I'm using a `static` method from `*Content` inside the `execute` method. Basically, my need is: the `contentType` parameter should accept any class object extended from `Content` (`PublicContent`, `AdminContent`, `PrivateContent`, etc)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Can you post the full types for `EntityProps` and `Entity`? as well as the full error - usually the error will complain about a specific incompatibility - in this case, it should tell you something along the lines of "constructor signature incompatible"

Comment: @Chase of course. The question was edited.

Comment: Please consider modifying your example code so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Qmbo4W) which demonstrates the issue you're facing and only the issue you're facing.  Ideally that would mean that you'd remove anything that doesn't relate to the problem.  This will allow people who want to help you to get to work on the solution to the problem without first having to put effort into producing the problem in the first place... and it increases the chance that answers will be applicable.

Comment: Hi @jcalz thanks for your comment. [Here](https://cutt.ly/fkFIjaP) a reproducible example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that superclass/subclass *constructors* do not always form a type hierarchy even if their *instances* do.  Let's look at an example:

```
class Foo {
  x = 1;
  constructor() { }
  static z = 3;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  y: string;
  constructor(y: number) {
    super()
    this.y = y.toFixed(1);
  }
}
```

Here, `class Bar extends Foo` means if you have a value of type `Bar`, you can assign it to a variable of type `Foo`:

```
const bar: Bar = new Bar(2);
const foo: Foo = bar; // okay
```

But if you try to assign the `Bar` *constructor* (of type `typeof Bar`) to a value of the same type as the `Foo` constructor (of type `typeof Foo`), it fails:

```
const fooCtor: typeof Foo = Bar; // error!
// Type 'new (y: number) => Bar' is not assignable to type 'new () => Foo'
```

That's because the `Bar` constructor requires a parameter of type `number` when you call its construct signature (i.e., `new Bar(2)`), while the `Foo` constructor takes no parameters at all (i.e., `new Foo()`).  If you try to use `Bar` as if it were the `Foo` constructor, and call it with no parameters, you'll get a runtime error:

```
const oopsAtRuntime = new fooCtor(); // TypeError: y is undefined
```

---

For the same reason, your `PublicContent` constructor is not assignable to `typeof Content`.  The former requires a construct signature parameter of type `PublicContentProps`, while the latter will accept any parameter of type that extends `ContentProps`.  If you try to use `PublicContent` as if it were the `Content` constructor, you might pass it a parameter of some type other than `PublicContentProps`, and that could lead to errors.

---

So let's step back. In fact you don't care if the object you pass as `contentType` is assignable to the `Content` constructor type because you're not going to call its construct signature with an arbitrary `ContentProps`.  You really only care about the type of its static `create()`  method. I'd be inclined to write `getContent()` as a generic function like this:

```
const getContent = <U extends ContentProps, T extends BaseEntity<U>>(input: {
  contentType: Pick<typeof Content, "create"> & (new (entityProps: U) => T);
  contentPropsType: new () => U;
}): U => { /* impl */ };
```

That should work similarly to your existing version on the inside of the function, and now you can call it without error, because `PublicContent` matches the `create` method of `Content`, as well as being a constructor of type `(new (entityProps: PublicContentProps) => PublicContent)`:

```
const entity = getContent({
  contentType: PublicContent,
  contentPropsType: PublicContentProps,
}); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-RBAwFIrDYgk-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-HiLctz5Gt3pJJoGi7ZYNgHUdhRhVpU2VcAS0koVOUvVQBqPb1H0FYE1XOLS9XfTNeUkux3lNX5rU2u1d2zCU1iqFQH3iAavYLRFYMxTaXZ6aaOUtlZ6MfMOVjdVQE6CdjO5mPKQjjAacKqJsuUZSSXYAERCdWnNfAAZEiiKzsZnlLiiXn5INy3JrTMHIp8PbSFevaK2gJAHHJEL1p+36-v+gHQMB7rU3MWt5kpYDiMgXDAjA3ZS1GagJuI5N0FQ8TSySO6e1WmgsG7HtezjsvXF25v1pbwXkVBzsFqk2H4URrRFE7I3iEjKPY-BpvRXLIPPdjF7B+x+fTYX7MhziG5cHkd5jJMRhAA)

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I needed to solve my problem. Excellent explanation! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the `Content` implements a simple interface, like `IContent`, and use this interface to get the `typeof` on `execute` parameter